# Dynamically change select input options in vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

How to change dynamically the options in a select dropdown v-model ?

I have 2 select inputs, one should change according to the others.

For example, if i select "fruits" the select display the fruits, if i select "vegetables" it displays the vegetables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use Vuejs, but after looking at the documentation:

```js
var TypesArr = {
                Fruit: [{ text: 'Apple', value: 'Apple' }, { text: 'Orange', value: 'Orange' }, { text: 'Mango', value: 'Mango' }],
                Meat:  [{ text: 'Steak', value: 'Steak' }, { text: 'Pork', value: 'Pork' }]
               }


var selectTwo = new Vue({
    el: '#select2',
    data: {
           selected: TypesArr['Fruit'][0],
           options: TypesArr['Fruit']
       },
       methods: {
         update: function (value)
         {
             this.options = TypesArr[value]
         }
       }
})


new Vue({
    el: '#select1',
    data: {
           selected: 'Fruit',
           options: [ { text: 'Fruit', value: 'Fruit' }, { text: 'Meat', value: 'Meat' } ]
       },
       methods: {
         onChange: function (event)
         {
             selectTwo.update(event.srcElement.value)
         }
       }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<select v-on:change="onChange" id="select1">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
    </option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: i'm tyring this with one vue instance https://jsfiddle.net/aj6g87dh/1/ why the second select is not bided on change ? the select is blank

Comment: @TheShun could you manage to get it working? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Mike - Did you get this going? Im new to vue and have the same issue! This post by fuzyCap does not seem to work anymore that possibly could be down to vue.js versions on the cdn its pulling in when you hit the "Run code snippet".

Comment: this is certainly not a solution. Every select element on the page requires a new Vue instance??

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are not really 'Vue' answers.

How you handle this depends on what you want to do with the select box. I'm assuming you'll to handle the input on a form.

Two options:

1. Use a Computed property
2. Use v-if to show different select boxes. This would be ideal if each select box has a different v-model

**Computed Property**

```
<template>
 <div class="container">
    <select id="firstInput" v-model="selected">
        <option v-for="option in firstInputOptions" :value="option">
        {{ option }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <select id="secondInput" v-model="secondInputSelected">
        <option v-for="option in secondInputOptions" :value="option">
        {{ option }}
        </option>
    </select>
 </div> <!-- /container -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    secondInputOptions(){
      return this.selected === 'fruit' ? this.fruit : this.vegetables
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      fruit: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'],
      vegetables: ['carrot', 'beet', 'celery'],
      firstInputOptions: ['fruit', 'vegetables']
      selected: 'fruit',
      secondInputSelected: ''
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

**Conditional Rendering**

```
<template>
 <div class="container">
    <select id="firstInput" v-model="selected">
        <option v-for="option in firstInputOptions" :value="option">
        {{ option }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <select id="secondInputFruit" v-model="selected" v-if="selected == 'fruit'">
        <option v-for="option in secondInputOptions" :value="option">
        {{ option }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <select id="secondInputVegetables" v-model="vegetableSelected" v-else-if="selected == 'vegetables'">
        <option v-for="option in secondInputOptions" :value="option">
        {{ option }}
        </option>
    </select>
 </div> <!-- /container -->
</template>

<script>
export default {   
  data () {
    return {
      fruits: ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'],
      fruitSelected: '',
      vegetables: ['carrot', 'beet', 'celery'],
      vegetableSelected: '',
      firstInputOptions: ['fruit', 'vegetables']
      selected: 'fruit' 
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using pure javascript

```js
var typesArr = {fruit: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Mango'], meat: ['Steak', 'Pork']}


function changeContext(value)
{
    if (typesArr.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
        var out = ''

        for (var i = 0; i < typesArr[value].length; i++) {
             out += '<option value="' + typesArr[value][i] + '">' + typesArr[value][i] + '</option>'
        }

        document.getElementById('select2').innerHTML = out
    }
}

changeContext('fruit')
```

```html
<select onchange="changeContext(this.value)">
    <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
    <option value="meat">Meat</option>
</select>

<select id="select2"></select>
```

Comment: looks great but this is pure javascript, i need an example with Vuejs