# Visible elements in options in select

Tags: vue.js

I would like to add all visible elements on my DOM to a select options. The select options should change as my elements are hidden using v-if. Is this possible? my code below does not update options

```
<select class="form-control-sm float-sm-right ml-2">
   <option
     v-for="n in visibleElements"
     v-bind:key="n.id"
     :value="n.id"
     >{{n.id}}
   </option>
</select>

methods:{
  visibleElements(){
    // I will have some kind of loop - for the time being showing one element
    var elements = []
    if (document.getElementById(`#el-1584610039188`)){
      elements.push({id:'1584610039188'})
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to answer your Q (Your code is missing -- add code snippet).

Anyway, general outline:

**v-model="selected" basic example:**

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      selected: ''
    }
  })
</script>
```

## v-if

Now use `selected` value inside `v-if` to show/hide `paris` div for example:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option>London</option>
    <option>Paris</option>
    <option>New York</option>
  </select>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>

  <div v-if="selected === 'London'">
    <h2>London is the capital and largest city of England and the United Kingdom.</h2>
  </div>
  <div v-if="selected === 'Paris'">
    <h2>Paris is the capital and most populous city of France</h2>
  </div>
  <div v-if="selected === 'New York'">
    <h2>The City of New York, usually known as either New York City (NYC), is the most populous city in the United States.</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      selected: ''
    }
  })
</script>
```

### v-for and data

Base on these ideas you could create more modular `DRY` code.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
    <option v-for="(item, index) in cities">
      {{ item.city }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>

  <ul v-for="(item, index) in cities">
    <li v-if="selected === item.city">
      <h2>{{ item.city }}</h2>
      <p>{{ item.descrtiption }}</p>
    </div>
  </ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      cities: [
        { city: 'London', descrtiption: "London is the capital and largest city of England and the United Kingdom."},
        { city: 'Paris', descrtiption: "Paris is the capital and most populous city of France." },
        { city: 'New York', descrtiption: "The City of New York, usually known as either New York City (NYC), or simply New York (NY), is the most populous city in the United States." }
      ],
      selected: ''
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I dont want to hide/ unhide divs but remove the option 'London' for example from the select if the div is not showing

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot ("your flow"). Sound like a very very specific UI idea. Hard to answer like this (Also it be helpful to add code snippet of your current code). Do you talk about the modular rendering of your select menu +- this concept? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438924/dynamically-change-select-input-options-in-vuejs-2